# How to unable mail.example.com from browser (ISPConfig)?

Tags: security, email, ssl

I am running under Debian 7 + ISPConfig 3.

I have recently configured the dns (at OVH web hosting service) so that ISPConfig manages the dns zone. For foobar.com, I have a MX record that points to mail.example.com (default behavior of ISPConfig when creating a dns zone).

I have succesfully connected my Mail program via IMAP on mail.foobar.com (SSL port 993) and SMTP on mail.example.com (SSL port 465).

**However**, I can go to mail.example.com with my browser ! and it displays

> It works!
>
> This is the default web page for this server.
>
> The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

Is there a security issue ? How can I disable access for browsers ?

Comment: It means that a web server (presumably Apache) is installed on mail.example.com. If you do not want there to be a webserver, I suggest that you uninstall it.

Comment: I need to run example.com (as well as www.example.com and other subdomains) but how can I forbid access to mail.example.com from basic http/https ? Is it something to change in the vhost, in apache directive ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using the same IP address for multiple services on the same computer, it's somewhat less than trivial to lock access via port 80 for only one of them. Here are some alternative, in increasing levels of complexity:

- Set up a virtual host with the name `mail.example.com` and have that one either return a redirect to `www.example.com`, or return `403 Forbidden`
- Get a second IP address that you use for the mail service, and don't let apache listen to that IP address
- Set up your firewall to filter packets to port 80 containing the string `Host: mail.example.com`. This will cause an increased load on the server since it makes the firewall check the contents on each packet rather than just filtering based on target port

Comment: Ok, so I took your logic and created a subdomain `mail.example.com` that redirects to `example.com` ! Is this an acceptable approach ?

Comment: It's one of the acceptable approaches.